# Scheme ill-formed special form let

Tags: scheme, dijkstra, let

I am trying to write a scheme program which is Dijkstra's Shortest Algorithm. In a procedure when I am relaxing the edges I get the error that

> ;Ill-formed special form: (let (...) ())

Code of my procedure is,

```
(define relax-over-edge 
   (lambda (distlist edge min-pair)
     ( if (null? distlist)
       ()
       (if (equal? (cadr edge) (caar distlist)) 
            (if (> (cdar distlist) (+(cdr min-pair) (cddr edge)))
                (let (((cdar distlist) (+ (cdr min-pair) (cddr edge)) )) ())
                ()
            )
            (relax-over-edge (cdr distlist) edge min-pair)
        )
     )  
   )
)
```

Thank you very much already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is an ill-formed `let`:

```
(let (((cdar distlist)
       (+ (cdr min-pair) (cddr edge)))) 
  '())
```

What were you trying to do? assigning the `(+ (cdr min-pair) (cddr edge))` expression to the element in the `(cdar distlist)` position? that's definitely *not* the way lists work in Scheme (at least not the *immutable* lists), you can't assign a value to a position like that. Besides, only variables can be declared in the left side of a binding in a `let` expression, and not other expressions (like in your code).

You'll have to rethink your algorithm, either use a `vector`  (which *does* support in-place modification of an element in a given position), or check the documentation of the Scheme interpreter you're using, to see what does it say about mutable pairs and lists.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because the body of your `let` form is just `()`, which is not a valid expression that can be evaluated.  Quoting the [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) manual:

> syntax: (let bindings body)
>        BINDINGS has the form
>
> ```
>       ((VARIABLE1 INIT1) ...)
>
>  that is zero or more two-element lists of a variable and an
>  arbitrary expression each.  All VARIABLE names must be distinct.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>     * The expressions in BODY are evaluated in order, and the value
>       of the last expression is returned as the value of the `let'
>       expression.
> ```